# SSL secure entire Frontend (all pages)

Tags: magento-1.9, frontend, ssl, https, secure

I run a store selling digital products and for me it is very important to show customers that my ENTIRE store is safe. Also Google have started to reward sites ussing SSL.
http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.se/2014/08/https-as-ranking-signal.html

I would like to use SSL (https) on all my Frontend pages in Magento. I have searched the forum and Google for answers and/or extensions but without result.

Does anyone know how to achieve this? Also, should i except any problems when doing this? I know that the speed will be reduced but that is OK.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The redirect to HTTPS root has nothing to do with the unsafe URL setting and the `.htaccess` setting suggested is not required.

If you have issues when redirecting from `http://yoursite.com/your_product.html` to `https://yoursite.com/` when using HTTPS, just go to:

`System` -> `Configuration` -> `General` -> `Web` -> `Redirect options`

And set:

`Auto-redirect to Base URL` -> `No`

If you need to fix broken URLs from broken addons/styles by changing `href="http://somewhere...` or `src="http://somewhere..."` into `href="//somewhere...` and `src="//somewhere..."` as usual to prevent mixed content issues. Of course, all external services should support HTTPS, but keep in mind the slowdown of having external resources.

Answer (score 14):

ITS NOT THAT SIMPLE... There is a problem with changing the store unsecured url to https. Any links to existing pages, including links from ads, indexed pages in Google, etc, that point to http://yoursite.com/your_product.html will be redirected to https://yoursite.com/

You will need to go through your theme and make sure that there are no references to http:

and then...

You will also need to redirect all http: requests to https: in your htaccess file with code similar to this:

```
############################################
## REDIRECT TO HTTPS ALWAYS
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !443
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

it will need to be inserted somewhere after this in your existing htaccess file:

```
############################################
## enable rewrites
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine on
```

You will need to adjust this to your specific situation and server set up.

Comment: Hi Jon, Thank you very much for this information. It will for sure help me when it is time to secure the shop!

Answer (score 13):

Set your base url for both your secured and unsecured site to `https://yoursite.com/`. That's all you need to do.

Comment: Hi Pronto!

Thanks for your answer. Is it really that simple? I have read some (http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/9891/13106) about issues due to extensions and modifications when using SSL. My guess would be that if i use SSL on all pages these issues would increase even more - what do you think?

Comment: I explained how to activate SSL for Magento front end, provided that you already have it. How to acquire and install SSL certificate is a general web server configuration issue and sort of off-topic for this SE.

Comment: @Pronto I believe Tobias was asking if it affects Magento extensions, rather than _how to aquire and install SSL certificate_

Comment: This one is the best solution.

Answer (score 5):

My suggestion is, hold your horses.

For example, if you are using Magento Enterprise Edition, HTTPS for the whole site will stop Magento’s Full Page Cache from working. We created a fix, for anyone to use - https://github.com/elastera/EnterprisePageCacheSSL (your feedback is greatly appreciated).

Your Page Load time could be increased significantly, due to SSL handshakes and possibly many 3rd parties scripts.

If you use a CDN, make sure you don't end-up paying an arm and a leg for installing a custom SSL certificate on their edges.

I recently wrote a blog post with details regarding this very topic: "[Why Google’s advice on HTTPS will screw your Magento site](http://www.elastera.com/blog/why-google-advice-on-https-will-screw-your-magento-site/)"

Sorry if I did provide a step by step how-to guide, but I hope I made clear possible obstacles ahead of you.

Answer (score 0):

For Magento CE 1.9.4.3, I needed to set

Use Secure URLs in Frontend = Yes
Use Secure URLs in Admin = Yes

in admin > System > Configuration > Secure:

[image]

I didn't do any other configuration at the server level.