# site wide update url to secure in magento 1

Tags: magento-1.9

I have a question can you help me about this one. I want a site wide update of url to secure url in the site in magento 1. SSL is already installed.

can you please teach me the proper process.

Thanks,
MazeStricks

Comment: [link1](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/31964/ssl-secure-entire-frontend-all-pages) , [link2](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/107083/redirect-all-http-request-to-https/107086)  & [link3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28167858/redirect-all-http-urls-to-https-for-frontend-in-magento)  & [link4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18631381/redirect-entire-pages-on-http-to-https-in-magento) may help.....

Comment: How about the Mixed Content how should I deal with them?